# Identify app icon that looks like a letter "b"

Tags: app-icons

Anyone know what this one is? It was on a screen cap I received of a Galaxy S5.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- Its the icon of application named Bixby in Samsung devices.
- Bixby is a virtual assistant developed by Samsung Electronics.